# Exclude dates from query that have already been found

Tags: mysql

I have a database table `availabilities` with the following columns:

```
+-----------------+
| availabilities  |
+-----------------+
| id              |
| available       |
| day_of_week     |
| start           |
| end             |
| start_time      |
| end_time        |
| created_at      |
| updated_at      |
+-----------------+
```

And a row in this table would look like this:

```
id | available | day_of_week | start      | end        | start_time | end_time | created_at          | updated_at
1  | 1         | 1           | 1995-07-29 | 2022-04-27 | 16:47:46   | 21:21:13 | 2021-09-13 11:11:54 | 2021-09-13 11:11:54
2  | 0         | 6           | 1993-11-13 | 2022-08-24 | 08:47:13   | 18:04:43 | 2021-09-13 11:11:54 | 2021-09-13 11:11:54
```

And I'm trying to find a way (if it's even possible) to exclude dates that are already found in the query to limit the amount of data I need to sift through. Currently I have a query that looks for any availability that has a date between a start date (2020-12-03) and an end date (2020-12-09):

```
select *
from `availabilities`
where
    (
      `start` >= '2020-12-03' #         +++++++++
      and `start` <= '2020-12-09' #  ---++++
      and `end` >= '2020-12-09'
    )
    or (
      `start` <= '2020-12-03' #        +++++++++
      and `end` >= '2020-12-09' #         ++
    )
    or (
      `start` <= '2020-12-03' #        +++++++++
      and `end` >= '2020-12-03' #           ++++---
      and `end` <= '2020-12-09'
    )
    or (
      `start` >= '2020-12-03' #         +++++++++
      and `end` <= '2020-12-09' #    ---+++++++++---
    )
```

So for instance if I had 2 rows with both the same day_of_week and the date I'm looking for is within the start and end dates I would only want to get the newest one regardless of available state.

I can't use a limit of 7 (for day_of_week) since it's possible it have more than 1 row with the same day_of_week and it's also possible to have more than 1 row for the dates I'm filtering. E.G. with relevant columns:

```
id | available | day_of_week | start      | end
 1 | 1         | 4           | 2020-08-05 | 2020-09-05
 2 | 0         | 4           | 2020-09-06 | 2020-10-01
```

Using 7 union's with each a different `day_of_week` with a limit also doesn't work because it's possible to have more than one row in the given filter (see example above).

Or using recursive but I've only used recursive for a parent_id to the same table so I wouldn't know where to start looking.

**EDIT:**
Following dump can be used: https://pastebin.com/kchD6sTw

For an example using the dump data we can look at `day_of_week = 3`. If the filter would be set as: `start: '2009-01-01', end:  '2021-01-01'` the expected return would be rows: 60 & 46 (ordered desc on `created_at` and `id`)

Because row 60 has a date range from `2010-04-15 → 2022-05-28` the missing piece to the filter would be from `2009-01-01 → 2010-04-14` meaning row 46 has this cover with his date range of `2005-10-11 → 2021-12-29` but currently row 47 would also be returned and be unused data since this technically also falls (partially) in between the filter with a date range of `2020-08-12 → 2022-03-01`

Comment: Provide source structure as CREATE TABLE script. Provide sample data as INSERT INTO script. Provide desired output for provided sample data strictly. Add explanations which refers to definite sample values.

Comment: @Akina I have added a pastebin with an sql dump and dummy data, additionally added an example using this dummy data. Ignore the `odd_week_number` column since it's not used in this case

Comment: *And I'm trying to find a way (if it's even possible) to exclude dates that are already found in the query to limit the amount of data I need to sift through.* Does this may be formulated as: find the shortest rows group which matches to specified day of week and completely covers each date in specified dates range? PS. your dump as a fiddle - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c47d6a81173000ab64421d327988cb42

Comment: maybe if you formulate it like  inputs : .....
wanted output: .... i didnt get it fully, maybe i have a problem ...

Comment: @Akina it's not the shortest row but the newest ones, maybe a "real world" example would be easier to understand: If I told you I'm available every monday from 9h-17h for a whole year. A week later I tell you that in August I'm not available anymore on monday. A week after that I tell you again that in August I'm back available but only after 18h. You'd forget that I've told you that I'm not available on monday in August since the newer data overwrites this but using the query it would still be in there and that's my problem.